# Regex to match everything outside of a regex pattern

Tags: javascript, html, regex

So I'd like to use javascript to replace all the words outside of HTML tags in a body of text. Check the explanation below.

I'd like to convert this:

```
<tag with-attr="something"></tag><tag>Text to match</tag><tag>Text to Match</tag>
```

...to this:

```
<tag with-attr="something"></tag><tag>Manipulated Text</tag><tag>Manipulated Text</tag>
```

Now, I have a regular expression that can match all the tags and its containing text:

```
\<[^>]*\>
```

But I'm not sure how to `invert` the expression, so to speak.

**EDIT**
Also, I'm looking to use the `replace` / `match` functions, not `split`, since I want to retain the tag information and spit the a working page back out with the new information.

Comment: use split() instead of match().

Comment: you ask for : `\>[^<]*\<` ? (switch > and < )

Comment: @dandavis I don't want to lose the tags because I'm doing a replacement of an entire webpage so I need the tag information afterwards. I want to use the replace function.

Comment: @BMW That expression will include the angle brackets which I don't want as part of the match.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with RegExp ....

Comment: fun fact: "".split() will keep tags or anything else you wrap in parens in the RegExp.

Comment: @dandavis So say I have an array of the manipulated strings... how would I place them back into their proper places on the page?

Comment: @dandavis I waas about to post that as an answer. You do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a paren-including split() RegExp and further array methods make "stream processing" fairly simple:

```
'<tag with-attr="something"></tag><tag>Text to match</tag>Text to Match<tag>'
  .split(/(<[^>]+>)/).map(function(x,i){
  if(!(i%2) && x){ x= escape(x); }
  return x;
}).join("");
```

example output:

```
"<tag with-attr="something"></tag><tag>Text%20to%20match</tag>Text%20to%20Match<tag>"
```

the escape() is just to show that the textContent has indeed been altered...
i only vouch for input close to your example. deeply nested or invalid HTML might fool any RegExp, but i'm sure someone else will bring that up...

Comment: Wow, very interesting I will try that out now.

Comment: Thank you so much, I guess I was looking in the wrong place for my solution. Learned something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
/>([^<>]*\w)</
```

demo here : http://rubular.com/r/2QPLjOeMAu

Now you just need to replace the content like this :

```
var str = '<tag with-attr="something"></tag><tag>Text to match</tag><tag>Text to Match</tag>';
var res = str.replace(/>([^<>]*\w)</g, '>Manipulated text<');
console.log(res);
```